# How to change the color depth?

Tags: 10.04, xorg, colors

I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed on a Dell C600 and the highest available resolution is 800x600. From my previous I remember 1024x768 would work after setting the colour depth to 16bit, but there is no `xorg.conf` in `/etc/X11` anymore. So, how can the colour depth be changed on lucid lynx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new xorg.conf by switching into a virtual virtual console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + (<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>)) and running `sudo service gdm stop`.

Then run `Xorg -configure` (yes, it should be `Xorg`, not `xorg`).
If you had an old xorg.conf file in /etc/X11/ you'd first back that up by doing `sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup`.

Then move your newly created xorg.conf to /etc/X11/ by running `sudo mv xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf` and restart gdm by running `sudo service gdm start`.

Then you can change the color depth in there by finding the appropriate section and changing/adding whatever's in there to `DefaultDepth    16`

Comment: Thanks, that changes the depth. Unfortunately, there seem to be more steps necessary, I [still cannot change the resolution to 1024x768](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/1571/how-to-change-the-resolution-of-an-ati-rage-mobility-128-above-800x600).

Comment: @IngoGerth: gnome's philosophy I guess... "Let's assume the dumbest possible user and insult even _them_ by hiding important options"

Answer (score 2):

Try doing [this step](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9362728&postcount=2), but before you get to the `sudo service xdm start` part, change the screen section (within the xorg.conf file) to something like:

```
Section "Screen"
Identifier    "Default Screen"
Monitor        "Configured Monitor"
Device        "Configured Video Device"
DefaultDepth    16
Modes        "1024x768"
EndSection
```

Comment: replace `xdm` with `gdm` and it's fine

Answer (score 0):

The following is verified on Ubuntu 13.04:

Try doing this step: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9362728#post9362728 , but before you get to the `sudo service gdm` start part, change (or add if there were none) the screen section (within the xorg.conf file) to something like:

```
Section "Screen"
Identifier    "Default Screen"
Monitor        "Configured Monitor"
Device        "Configured Video Device"
DefaultDepth    24
EndSection
```

In my case, depth used to be 32; I changed it to 24 to free some display memory so that I can plug a huge LCD display to it.