# How to change the color depth in lubuntu to 24-bit?

Tags: lubuntu, color-depth

I just installed Lubuntu 13.04 on a very old pc of mine.

- intel p4 2.6 ghz processor
- some local made motherboard
- 40 gb / 512 ram.

The color depth seems to stuck in 8 bit mode. How to change it to 24bit?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/1562/147044) will help you.

Comment: THIS SOLVED IT !!!

http://samuelmartin.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/enabling-resolutions-in-ubuntu-12-04-lubuntu-12-04/